# PHP не успевает выполниться до JavaScript | веб-сайт

Tags: javascript, php, html

У меня есть 3 файла: index.html, main.php и main.js. Идея заключается в том, что на сайте должны отобразиться определенные картинки, пути к которым будут вытащены из базы данных. Однако, к сожалению, работает раз через раз (раз загружу сайт – все хорошо, второй – ошибка: JavaScript не может найти функцию getImagesPaths). Подскажите, пожалуйста, что можно сделать, чтобы первым исполнялся гарантированно .php файл, затем – .html и, наконец, .js?

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">

<?php
    include "php/main.php";
?>

<head>
    <!--
        здесь подключение .css файлов
        задание title и meta данных
    -->
</head>

<body>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    
    <!--
        здесь разметка страницы
        3 "слота" для размещения картинок
    -->
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var paths;
        
        try {
            paths = getImagesPaths();
        }
        catch(error) {
            // именно здесь ИНОГДА ошибка: getImagesPaths is not defined
            alert('Error: ' + error);
        }
        init();
    </script>
</body>
```

main.js

```
function init() {
    init.images = [];
    
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        init.images[i] = document.getElementById("img" + (i + 1));
        init.images[i].src = paths[i];
    }
}
```

main.php

```
    <?php

    // здесь подключение к серверу БД
    // запросы к базе данных
    // и чтение результатов в $result
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function  getImagesPaths() {
        return <?php echo json_encode($result); ?>
    }
</script>
```

Еще раз хотел бы подчеркнуть, что иногда все работает корректно, а иногда я получаю ошибку "ReferenceError: getImagesPaths is not defined". Спасибо!

Comment: php - серверный язык, он ВСЕГДА выполняется первым. `return JSON.parse('<?= json_encode($result); ?>');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Попробуйте сделать php файл, который будет отдавать список изображений, а в JS стчитесь в него с помощью fetch.

```js
const getImagesList = () => fetch('./scripts/get-images-list.php');

getImagesList().then((data) => {
  /**
  * Здесь делаете, что хотите с полученными данными
  */
});
```

---

2. По семантике тег скрипт надо вставить в body, перед подключение других скриптов, либо в head.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
<head>
    <!--
        здесь подключение .css файлов
        задание title и meta данных
    -->
</head>

<body>
    <?php include "php/main.php"; ?>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    
    <!--
        здесь разметка страницы
        3 "слота" для размещения картинок
    -->
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var paths;
        
        try {
            paths = getImagesPaths();
        }
        catch(error) {
            // именно здесь ИНОГДА ошибка: getImagesPaths is not defined
            alert('Error: ' + error);
        }
        init();
    </script>
</body>
```